# Linq c# Querying based on a Variable

Tags: c#, linq

I want to be able to do something like this below where I select the field based on a variable name. The below doesn't work and i cant find a solution without doing a big switch statement.

```
var guidId = new Guid("");
var fieldName= "somefield";

var query =
 from c in Financials
 where c.GuidId == guidId 
 select **fieldName**;
```

Is their a simple way to do this?

Thanks Austin

Comment: Can't you just do "select myVariable"

Comment: So `**fieldName**` actually is a string which is the name of the property? Dynamic LINQ [> here <](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Comment: can explain more about the term *simple*?

Comment: @JW. By simple i mean way of doing this without a massive switch..

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
select c.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName).GetValue(c, null)
```

I found this on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp). If my answer doesn't work for some reason in the query you can just `select c` and then just put it through the method as shown in the answer to the SO question.

Note: It returns an `object`, so be careful!

Comment: After quite a bit of trail and error i managed to get the function on the link to work. Do you know if this will have much effect on performance as i have heard reflection is bad?

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection:

```
select c.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName).GetValue(c, null);
```

It's really the only way to get the value of a property by name.